# Verifying valid Parse and Facebook session while also allowing sign up without Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

As noted in the **Bypassing the Login** section of [Parse's tutorial for integrating Facebook login](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook), you need to verify both that the cached user exists and that that user is linked with Facebook, and if not then show the login screen. This presents a problem for apps that allow creating an account without using Facebook. Because that user will never be linked to Facebook, it would always show the login screen. But if you only check that the user is cached, they could be unlinked from Facebook - essentially their session is not active. When that occurs you won't show the login screen and the requests will fail, I believe. (Or is this limited to requests the app makes with Facebook - can you still make requests for the Parse user in that situation?)

My question is, how can I properly verify the Parse user has an active session and if their account was tied to Facebook also ensure that is still active, otherwise show the login screen?

```
//TODO: How to make it work without a Facebook account
if PFUser.currentUser() == nil || !PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) {
    //show login screen
}
```

One solution could be to add a column to the User table that indicates if that user was created via Facebook login. And if that's set, then verify the account is still linked, otherwise don't. I'm wondering if there's a better way to obtain the correct behavior.

Comment: If the user is not linked with Facebook that does not mean that their session is necessarily invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your approach. Off the top of my head I don't know if you have access to the authData in the user table. If you do, then you would be able to get away with just checking that.

Comment: I ended up storing the Facebook id in a column in the User table.